# Compile Multiple Classes and pass command line arguments

Tags: java, javac

How would I compile two classes using command line(without the use of additional software) and pass arguments to it?

I've created myself a `sources.txt` file which contains definitions where each class is. I did this by using the following command

```
dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt
```

Then I try to do `javac @sources.txt` although that does not help as I'm getting the following error:

```
error: invalid flag: C:\Users\Adrian
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Additionally, my path does contain one space, after my username. Adrian $. So in sources.txt it looks like this: `C:\Users\Adrian $\`

I did try putting quotes around them or percentage sign but then I get error which specifies that the file was not found.

---

Full Main code:

```
package me.adrian;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            CSVoperator CSVfile = new CSVoperator();

            try {
                CSVfile.readCSV(args); //get args into there.
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compile directly by specifying multiple names in on command

```
javac file1.java file2.java
```

or by using `*`, all `.java` files that are in current directory will be compiled

```
javac *.java
```

Comment: Thanks! Although when I try to run them then I get _Error: Could not find or load main class *.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *.java_ I used java *.java to run it.

Comment: which operating system? , it works for me in windows @Adrian

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. jdk 11.0.1

Comment: okay, which version java? and do you any `.java` files in that directory, you should execute this  from that directory

Comment: Java version 8, update 191. My folder looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/FWiKihM . And yes, I'm nonstop within that directory.

Comment: do you have main method in that classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183800/discussion-between-deadpool-and-adrian).

Answer (score 0):

Since your paths contain space they has to be quoted. You can do it by iterating over `sources.txt` in a loop and quoting the entire line:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (sources.txt) DO "javac %%i"
```

or you can try `dir /x` to generate `sources.txt` with a short path as per [dir docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir)

> /x
>
> Displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file names. The display is the same as the display for /n, but the short name is inserted before the long name.

One way or another, scripting in Windows Batch sux.

Comment: If this would help then _%%i was unexpected at this time._

Comment: @Adrian the root cause is your paths containing a space. Since I'm not a windows batch expert nor I have access to windows command prompt I can't really help, sorry. Your goal is to run `javac "C:\Users\Adrian $\Project\File.java"` command or similar using escaped path to `File.java`.

Comment: My files finally do compile but they're "refusing" to run... Here's the image of my folder structure https://imgur.com/a/FWiKihM  .  I'm using _java Main_ command to compile it although it gives me the error _Error: Could not find or load main class Main_ and I am within the same directory as my Main class

Comment: @Adrian open a new question and post the entire `Main` class, there is not enough detail to answer this.

Comment: I have updated this question with my main.java code.

Comment: Use fully qualified class name `java me.adrian.Main`